# Does DispatchQueue(label: "com.myApp.serialQueue") run on the main thread?

Tags: ios, swift

I know  DispatchQueue.main.async {} runs on the main thread and  DispatchQueue.global.async {}
doesn't. But I can't find any documentation or past question about this:

```
private let myQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.myApp.serialQueue")

@objc func appBecameActive() {
    myQueue.async {
        stuff
    }
}
```

Is this running on the main thread or not? And therefore is not a good thing to have in appBecameActive() because appBecameActive because the applicationDidBecomeActive method is called on the main thread, and if stuff performs a lengthy operation it'd therefore block the main thread.

My app is hanging on launch, don't know how DispatchQueue() behaves

Comment: "Is this running on the main thread or not?" Does "this" mean `stuff`? Obviously not, it's running on your custom serial queue `myQueue`! Is this supposed be a trick question? If you wanted to ensure running on the main thread you'd have said DispatchQueue.main. "And therefore is not a good thing to have in appBecameActive()" No one can answer that except you. It depends what `stuff` is and what your goal is.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Only the main queue runs on the main thread. All other queues run on other, non-main, threads.

The use of `DispatchQueue(label:)` creates a new serial queue.

You can't create another main queue. There's only one main queue and it's created for you and accessed with `DispatchQueue.main`.

Given all of this, the "stuff" in you code is being run on a non-main queue and therefore a non-main thread. But that is as much as can be said without a lot more details of what "stuff" is and what it is doing.

That covers your main question. But you also mention that your app is hanging. The hang is beyond the scope of your question. But as general guidance, when the app hangs, pause the app in the debugger and look at all of the listed threads on the left side of the debugger. Look at the call stack for each thread and see where in your own code (or library code) it is stopped. From there you can hopefully determine the cause of the hang.

Comment: Don't conflate threads and queues.  Tasks dispatched on the main queue are guaranteed to run on the main thread. Tasks dispatched on other queues can run on any available thread, which may be the main thread.  When using GCD  think about queues, not threads.

Comment: @Paulw11
How can you guarantee that a task dispatched on a non-main queue will not run on the main thread?

Comment: You cannot. That is why you should not block threads. Threads are a limited resource and even blocking a non-main thread reduces the available threads. If you use GCD functions you won't block the thread because GCD is concerned with queues.